# My PHP script randomly can't read a post variable

Tags: php, html

I can't find a pattern to it, but in my captcha, my php script for confirming it randomly won't read the `$_POST` variable that was posted in the preceding HTML form.

```
<form name="post" action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="text-align: center;"><br>

        <div style="position: relative; top: -5px;">Song Title: <input type="text" name="Title" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9`\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\\\=\+\{\}\[\]]{2,40}" required></div><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000000">

        <div style="position: relative; top: 5px; left: 34px;">Song File (Mp3 only): <input type="file" accept="audio/mpeg" name="Audio" id="file1" onchange="getChange()"></div><br><br><br>

        <div style="position: relative; top: -5px;"><img src="captcha/CaptchaSecurityImages.php"><br>Security Code:<br>
            <input name="security_code" type="text" required><br><br>

        <div style="position: relative; top: -8px;">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" disabled>
        </div>

</form>
```

The submit button enables when the form's been filled out. It works fine.

The code to read it is:
`<?php echo $_POST['security_code'] ?>`

It works sometimes and it doesn't work other times. It often says I didn't enter anything in the security code box, even if I did. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Where is the PHP Code that returns that?

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump($_FILE);`

Comment: You don't need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as there is no file upload in your form

Comment: @Vector it's on the 6th line down

Answer (score 3):

dump the `$_POST` variable and see how the results looks like

```
print_r($_POST);
```

and you should see a result something like this

```
Array
(
    [security_code] => aaaa
    [MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 20000000
)
```

then you can know when in the randomness you can't read a `$_POST` data

Comment: I found the problem. It was the max_post_size in the `php.ini` file. Whenever something goes above it, it does not send any `$_POST` data at all.

Comment: Now you have solved it a simple `if` statement preventing form submission will be worth putting in place

Comment: That's what I'm going to do. I think I just check if the fields are empty, in which case that means the form didn't post because the post was too large.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It was the max_post_size in the php.ini file. Whenever something goes above it, it does not send any $_POST data at all.